Vertex AI - Categorizing text can get blocked for containing inappropriate content
I implemented Vertex AI to my Firebase functions in order to categorize content that users create. One of the categories I should be "Adult" however when the Vertex AI detects inappropriate text, it blocks the response and not categorizing anything. It just throws this error: The response was blocked because the input or response may contain descriptions of violence, sexual themes, or otherwise derogatory content. Please try rephrasing your prompt.
const textModel = 'gemini-1.5-flash';

const vertexAI = new VertexAI({ project: projectId, location: 'us-central1' });

// Instantiate Gemini models
const generativeModel = vertexAI.getGenerativeModel({
    model: textModel,
});

const textToCategorize = `Categorize this content: "${contentDocumentCategories}". Print only 1 of these categories and don't include anything else: Games, Movies & TV, Music, Celebrities, Humor, Pets & Animals, Food & Drink, Vehicles, Technology, Science, Travel & Transportation, Sports, Online Communities, Books & Literature, Anime & Manga, Comics, Shopping, Nature, Random, Toys, Memes, Business, Interests, People, Lifestyle, Politics, Adult.`;
const vertexRequest = {
    contents: [{ role: 'user', parts: [{ text: textToCategorize }] }],
};
const vertexResult = await generativeModel.generateContent(vertexRequest);crashing
const vertexResponse = vertexResult.response;

// Response
if (vertexResponse)
   console.log('Category: ', vertexResponse.candidates[0].content.parts[0].text);

How can I bypass this? I want it to detect inappropriate text and categorize it as instructed in the query.
